# R - Gap fill a time series

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series

I am trying to fill in the gaps in one of my time series by merging a full day time series into my original time series. But for some reason I get duplicate entries and all the rest of my data is NA.
My data looks like this:

```
> head(data)
                 TIME Water_Temperature
1 2016-08-22 00:00:00            81.000
2 2016-08-22 00:01:00            80.625
3 2016-08-22 00:02:00            85.000
4 2016-08-22 00:03:00            80.437
5 2016-08-22 00:04:00            85.000
6 2016-08-22 00:05:00            80.375

> tail(data)
                    TIME Water_Temperature
1398 2016-08-22 23:54:00              19.5
1399 2016-08-22 23:55:00              19.5
1400 2016-08-22 23:56:00              19.5
1401 2016-08-22 23:57:00              19.5
1402 2016-08-22 23:58:00              19.5
1403 2016-08-22 23:59:00              19.5
```

In between are some minutes missing (1403 rows instead of 1440). I tried to fill them in using:

```
data.length <- length(data$TIME)
time.min <- data$TIME[1]
time.max <- data$TIME[data.length]
all.dates <- seq(time.min, time.max, by="min")
all.dates.frame <- data.frame(list(TIME=all.dates))
merged.data <- merge(all.dates.frame, data, all=T)
```

But that gives me a result of 1449 rows instead of 1440. The first eight minutes are duplicates in the time stamp column and all other values in `Water_Temperature` are `NA`. Looks like this:

```
> merged.data[1:25,]
                  TIME Water_Temperature
1  2016-08-22 00:00:00                NA
2  2016-08-22 00:00:00            81.000
3  2016-08-22 00:01:00                NA
4  2016-08-22 00:01:00            80.625
5  2016-08-22 00:02:00                NA
6  2016-08-22 00:02:00            85.000
7  2016-08-22 00:03:00                NA
8  2016-08-22 00:03:00            80.437
9  2016-08-22 00:04:00                NA
10 2016-08-22 00:04:00            85.000
11 2016-08-22 00:05:00                NA
12 2016-08-22 00:05:00            80.375
13 2016-08-22 00:06:00                NA
14 2016-08-22 00:06:00            80.812
15 2016-08-22 00:07:00                NA
16 2016-08-22 00:07:00            80.812
17 2016-08-22 00:08:00                NA
18 2016-08-22 00:08:00            80.937
19 2016-08-22 00:09:00                NA
20 2016-08-22 00:10:00                NA
21 2016-08-22 00:11:00                NA
22 2016-08-22 00:12:00                NA
23 2016-08-22 00:13:00                NA
24 2016-08-22 00:14:00                NA
25 2016-08-22 00:15:00                NA

> tail(merged.data)
                    TIME Water_Temperature
1444 2016-08-22 23:54:00                NA
1445 2016-08-22 23:55:00                NA
1446 2016-08-22 23:56:00                NA
1447 2016-08-22 23:57:00                NA
1448 2016-08-22 23:58:00                NA
1449 2016-08-22 23:59:00                NA
```

Does anyone has an idea whats going wrong?

**EDIT:**

Using the xts and zoo package now to do the job by doing:

```
library(xts)
library(zoo)

df1.zoo<-zoo(data[,-1],data[,1])
df2 <- as.data.frame(as.zoo(merge(as.xts(df1.zoo), as.xts(zoo(,seq(start(df1.zoo),end(df1.zoo),by="min"))))))
```

Very easy and effective!

Comment: The code at the bottom can be shortened to library(zoo);
`library(zoo); z <- read.zoo(data, tz = ""); DF <- fortify.zoo(merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), by = "min")))); names(DF) <- names(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `merge` use `rbind` which gives you an irregular time series without `NA`s to start with. If you really want a regular time series with a frequency of say 1 minute you can build a time based sequence as an index and `merge` it with your data after ( after using `rbind`) and fill the resulting `NA`s with `na.locf`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well that doesn't change the problem. I can delete the duplicated afterwards, but I will still lose all the other data because they have been replaced by `NA`.

Comment: Okay that could work and I might try it later. But for now my edited version with zoo and xts works perfectly fine. Just to clarify, I want NA's where I gap filled the time series. But my first approach overwrote all other values in Water_Temperature with NA's as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can try merging with `full_join` from `tidyverse`

This works for me with two dataframes (daily values) sharing a column named date.

```
big_data<-my_data %>%
  reduce(full_join, by="Date")
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the other ways to fill missing gaps in time series is by using na.approx() function, which is part of zoo package.
Read more https://thedatahall.com/filling-gaps-in-time-series-and-panel-data-using-r/

Comment: The link is a helpful source, but you should included code showing the implementation of this function. The OP has provided a reproducible example with sample data.